# How to edit redirect link on an SWF Flash file?

Tags: flash

I have an SWF Flash file that redirects to a web page after playing. I want to change the address of the web page or remove the redirection. Is this possible without fla?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this Flash Decompiler. Just download the trialversion.
http://www.swf-to-fla.net/how-to/edit-links-in-swf/