# Add hyperlinks to SWF buttons

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, object, embed

I have an SWF file which I downloaded off the internet for studying purposes: http://binw.net/externalUIs/campaigns/skylandersSuperchargers/SkylandersSuperchargersMap_26_10_15.swf

There are different "locations" on the SWF file and I believe it is a map - for example, there's a fountain, a racing track, a tree and a castle. What I need to do is make all the different locations redirect to a different hyperlink when they're clicked..

I had a look at [How to edit redirect link on an SWF Flash file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647282/how-to-edit-redirect-link-on-an-swf-flash-file) and it suggested that I download the trial version of Flash Decompiler which I have done but I am lost at what to do subsequent to this.

Answer (score 4):

You need to decompile the swf then modify some code, then compile it to new one.

I have try on your swf,and when you click the location, it will redirect to the baidu website.

here is the [changed swf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ial675c7l04bjkh/aaa.swf)

You need two software, [JPEXS](https://www.free-decompiler.com/flash/) and [RABCDAsm](https://github.com/CyberShadow/RABCDAsm/)

**1. Decompile the swf and found the relative code**

JPEXS is used to decompiled the swf into code and png, jpg. You can find the code for the action when you click the city, I find it is Map Class, gotoLocation function.When I try to open your swf, it throws some error, and I found the class name and function name directly.

**2. Use RABCDAsm to disassemble the swf, get abc code**

RABCDAsm is  an ActionScript 3 assembler/disassembler, it will turn the swf into many files with asasm and abc type, then you can modify the file in your editor,and the RABCDAsm tool can make the files into a new swf.

So here is a problem, how can you want the target **Map** file in the generated files?
Try to search **Map.class.asasm** in the files, the same name of the decompiled class.

**3. Write a new Map class contain the gotoLocation function,get the target abc code**

You need to use new abc code to replace the abc code in the **Map.class.asasm**.
Try to make a project, then add a Class named Map, put a gotoLocation function in it like this.

```
package
{
   import flash.net.URLRequest;
   import flash.net.navigateToURL;
   import flash.events.MouseEvent;

   public class Map
   {
       public function Map()
       {
       }

       public function gotoLocation(param1:int) : void
       {
           if(param1 != 999)
           {
               navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.baidu.com"),"_blank");
            }
        }

        private function closeMap(param1:MouseEvent = null) : void
        {

        }
    }
```

}

Get the **release swf** of the new project,then repeat the second step, you will get the abc code of the class like this

```
  trait method QName(PackageNamespace(""), "gotoLocation")
  method
    refid "Map/instance/gotoLocation"
    param QName(PackageNamespace(""), "int")
    returns QName(PackageNamespace(""), "void")
    body
      maxstack 3
      localcount 2
      initscopedepth 4
      maxscopedepth 5
      code
      getlocal0
      pushscope

      getlocal1
      pushshort           999
      ifeq                L11

      findpropstrict      QName(PackageNamespace("flash.net"), "navigateToURL")
      findpropstrict      QName(PackageNamespace("flash.net"), "URLRequest")
      pushstring          "http://www.baidu.com"
      constructprop       QName(PackageNamespace("flash.net"), "URLRequest"), 1
      pushstring          "_blank"
      callpropvoid        QName(PackageNamespace("flash.net"), "navigateToURL"), 2

    L11:
        returnvoid
   end ; code
  end ; body
end ; method
end ; trait
```

It's easy to find the abc code by search function name.

**4. replace the abc code,create new swf with RABCDAsm**

use the new abc code to replace the target **body** part  in second step, then use RABCDAsm to generate the new swf.

The old abc code like this

```
trait method QName(PackageNamespace(""), "gotoLocation")
method
refid "com.binweevils.externalUIs.map:Map/instance/gotoLocation"
param QName(PackageNamespace(""), "int")
returns QName(PackageNamespace(""), "void")
body
  maxstack 2
  localcount 2
  initscopedepth 10
  maxscopedepth 11
  code
  getlocal0
  pushscope

  getlocal1
  pushshort           999
  ifeq                L21

  getlocal0
  getproperty         QName(PrivateNamespace(null, "com.binweevils.externalUIs.map:Map/instance#0"), "bin")
  getproperty         Multiname("crntLocID", [PrivateNamespace(null, "com.binweevils.externalUIs.map:Map/instance#0"), PackageNamespace(""), PackageNamespace("com.binweevils.externalUIs.map"), Namespace("http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin"), PrivateNamespace(null, "com.binweevils.externalUIs.map:Map/instance#1"), PackageInternalNs("com.binweevils.externalUIs.map"), ProtectedNamespace("com.binweevils.externalUIs.map:Map"), StaticProtectedNs("com.binweevils.externalUIs.map:Map"), StaticProtectedNs("flash.display:MovieClip"), StaticProtectedNs("flash.display:Sprite"), StaticProtectedNs("flash.display:DisplayObjectContainer"), StaticProtectedNs("flash.display:InteractiveObject"), StaticProtectedNs("flash.display:DisplayObject"), StaticProtectedNs("flash.events:EventDispatcher")])
  getlocal1
  ifeq                L19
```

**NOTICE**
you can find the RABCDAsm for windows [here](http://files.thecybershadow.net/RABCDAsm/),and you can find the RABCDAsm commands in its github page.

At Last, some times you don't need RABCDAsm if the project is simple.Try to put the decompiled code into a project, then fix the compile error.In this case, you need luck.

Comment: is there any problem with JPEXS for both code editing and saving back the swf file?

Comment: @payamsbr I think it's same to get the right result for different tools. But I haven't used JPEXS for saving back the swf file, only for decompile and dump the swf from memory.

Answer (score 2):

SWF file is compiled and zipped ActionScript code. You can't change anything inside (in general) without recompiling. So, you need to decompile the swf you have and hopefully, you'll get a set of files. Then you need to find the parts of code where the hyperlink addresses are located and change them. Then you need to compile the code back, and, if you are lucky enough, you'll get the swf with changed hyperlinks. Imho, it's a pretty bad idea.